# While using this algorithm to approximate pi, I'm getting: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python, pi

To find the real value of pi I'm using:

```
from mpmath import mp
prec= 10**4 # precision equal to 10^4 digits
mp.dps = prec 
# mp.pi is the value of pi with 10^4 digits of precision
```

I'm using the BBP formula to approximate pi:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec=prec
pi = sum(1/Decimal(16)**k *
          (Decimal(4)/(8*k+1) -
           Decimal(2)/(8*k+4) -
           Decimal(1)/(8*k+5) -
           Decimal(1)/(8*k+6)) for k in range(20))
```

I want to see how close this approximation is from the real pi, so

```
if(abs(mp.pi - pi) < 0.001): print("true")
else: print("false")
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 23, in <module>
   if(abs(mp.pi - pi) < 0.001): print("true")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'constant' and 'decimal.Decimal'
```

I tried converting the constant mp.pi to a decimal but this is not allowed.

Comment: mpmath and Decimal both essentially define brand new number types that aren't designed to work with each other. Both might work with regular floats and ints though. 
I think your options are either to take multiple steps to convert one to the other (which might mean you lose some accuracy and defeat the whole point of this excercise) or you change to only use just one library and abandon the other. 
Given your use case I'd switch to just using mpmath and get rid of Decimal.

Comment: @deceze there's one one instance of negation in the entire code, 2nd to last line, `mp.pi - pi`, `mp.pi` is mpmath's custom number type, `pi` is defined before as an instance of `decimal.Decimal`. They don't accept each other as args to `__sub__()`

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 Not sure if I remember correctly, but, I saw that the Decimal used in the BBP algorithm is to have more accuracy, and maybe removing it will lose precision. Do you have any suggestion on how to proceed?

Comment: I think its the precision. If I use a `pi` with 4k digits, it works. But fails in the 4300 range. Something overflows in the `mp.pi` calculation and gets categorized as a type error.

Comment: @tdelaney I changed the precision variable to 10^3 and it works, but with larger values does not.